# Token Replacement using Coldfusion and MSSQL 2005

Tags: coldfusion

I ran across Raymond Camden's blog, http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2010/11/2/Building-a-simple-ColdFusion-TokenTemplate-System, and it is almost perfect for what I want to do with it.  I'm stuck on how to dynamically create this line of code:

`<cfset s = {name="Luke Skywalker", newslettertype="Lightsabers", producttype="swords", source="The Empire", rate="18"}>`

My table contains TERM and REPLACEMENTTERM as in:

```
SELECT     TERM, REPLACEMENTTERM
FROM       REPLACEMENTTEXT
```

I know this wont work but for visual of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
<cfset s = {<cfoutput query="data">#data.term#="#data.replacementterm#"<cfif data.currentrow lt data.recordcount>,</cfoutput></cfif>}>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<cfset s = {} />
<cfloop query="data">
    <cfset s[term] = replacementterm />
</cfloop>
```

That should accomplish what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously??? Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel when there is already two ports of the most popular templating languages over to CFML? They even have tests written against them.

Liquid: [Homepage](http://liquidmarkup.org/) | [CFML Port](https://github.com/rip747/cfml-liquid)

Mustache: [Homepage](http://mustache.github.com/) | [CFML Port](https://github.com/rip747/Mustache.cfc)

Comment: What are you trying to say?  I thought about having the document appear and then updating the values from a json call - which kind of resembles the mustache approach link you posted above (or at least the link I followed once I was on mustache's web site).  Otherwise, I'm not sure what your answer is proposing.  Additional feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: what i'm saying is stop trying to write some half baked template language based off of a demonstration in a blog post and actually use a real one for what you're trying to do. Mustache and Liquid are battle tested and used out there in the wild. Not for nothing but if you're posting a question about the first step in token replacement, chances are you're going to have a hard time if you ever decide to add conditional statements.

Comment: you are 100% correct in that the conditional statements are posing a problem.  Thank goodness for S.O. though so issues like this can be presented and corrected.